# how i make filter search in vue js with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, filter, vuejs2

can i write a filter search code with just data and methods function?

i try do this :

```
var fil = new Vue ({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                search: '',
                proL: ['css', 'c++', 'cs#'],
            },
            methods: {
                filter: function(){

                        var search_key = this.search.val();
                        
                        this.proL.filter(function(){
                            this.proL.toggle(this.proL.text().indexOf(search_key) > -1);
                        });

                }
            }
        });
```

and this is the html code

```
<div id="app">
        <div >
          <input @keyup="filter()" type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search title.."/>
        </div>

        <div id="pro">
            <h4 v-for="item in proL">{{item}}</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be using `computed` handler

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
      search: '',
      proL: ['css', 'c++', 'cs#'],
  },
  computed: {
    filteredProL(){
      if(this.search === '') return this.proL; // If search input is empty then display all items
      else return this.proL.filter(e => e.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search) > -1) // Working logic
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div >
    <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search title.."/>
  </div>

  <div id="pro">
      <h4 v-for="item in filteredProl">{{item}}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a `computed` property to define the filtered items and use an arrow function as `filter` function callback in order to get access to `this`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
      search: '',
      proL: ['css', 'c++', 'cs#'],
  },
  computed: {
    filtered(){
      return this.proL.filter(e => e.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()))
    }
  }
})

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div >
    <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search title.."/>
  </div>

  <div id="pro">
      <h4 v-for="item in filtered">{{item}}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can i do it without computed ?

Comment: Computed is the best for this scenario since its dynamic by nature

Comment: Hey mate, sure you can, but in my opinion computed propery is for this kind of things,